# Como fazer um while sem travar a aplicação em Java

Tags: java, multithreading, async

Estou construindo uma aplicação na faculdade que preciso rodar um código durante 2 minutos e de minuto a minuto fazer uma avaliação do sistema e das variáveis que estão nele. Já procurei na internet, uns dizem pra usar `new Thread()` outros para usar `new Runnable()`, outros pra usar as 2 formas e mesmo assim chego em uma solução.

Fiz um exemplo com o mínimo que preciso para minha aplicação funcionar, preciso apenas instanciar essa classe 2 vezes e que as 2 consigam imprimir um conteúdo qualquer no console ao mesmo tempo.

```java
package teste;

public class Log {

    public boolean parar;

    public Log(String n) {

        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
        parar = false;

        int dTest, dNow = Integer.parseInt(f.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

        while (!parar) {

            dTest = Integer.parseInt(f.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

            if (dNow != dTest) {
                dNow = dTest;
                System.out.println(dNow + " | " + n);
            }

        }

    }

}

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("teste de classe (1 para o sistema)");

        Log foo = new Log("foo"), bar = new Log("bar");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scan.nextInt() != 1) {
            System.out.println("------");
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);

    }

}
```

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso (ou pelo menos uma que rode as 2 instâncias e meu sistema fique aberto podendo ler isso, como uma leitura em tempo real)?

Comment: Você não pode usar um while como uma função de tempo real, isso o fará travar sem sombras de dúvida

Comment: Você pode colocar uma função que rode de tantos em tantos tempos para fazer o que deseja, com tempo de 10, 20 ou 30 segs, um while fara o processo mais de mil vezes a cada segundo, isso é desnecessário e nenhuma maquina aguenta

Comment: Não entendi o que você está tentando fazer. Esse código só tem uma thread, então não entendo o que você está tentando paralelizar. Além disso, não entendi o que é que a sua classe `Log` está esperando e porquê.

Comment: Além disso, não há nenhum lugar onde você faça `parar = true;` ou mesmo tente fazer isso. Dessa forma, a função `Log` será sempre um laço infinito.

Comment: Vejo aqui um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132): "*Estou construindo uma aplicação na faculdade que preciso rodar um código durante 2 minutos e de minuto a minuto fazer uma avaliação do sistema e das variáveis que estão nele.*" - Esse é o problema X, é o que você precisa resolver. "*Fiz um exemplo com o mínimo que preciso para minha aplicação funcionar, preciso apenas instanciar essa classe 2 vezes e que as 2 consigam imprimir um conteúdo qualquer no console ao mesmo tempo.*" - Esse é o Y, algo que você acha que pode resolver o problema, mas não sabe como ou porquê.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, vejo aqui um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132):

> Estou construindo uma aplicação na faculdade que preciso rodar um código durante 2 minutos e de minuto a minuto fazer uma avaliação do sistema e das variáveis que estão nele.

Esse é o problema X, é o que você precisa resolver.

> Fiz um exemplo com o mínimo que preciso para minha aplicação funcionar, preciso apenas instanciar essa classe 2 vezes e que as 2 consigam imprimir um conteúdo qualquer no console ao mesmo tempo.

Esse é o problema Y, algo que você acha que pode resolver o problema, mas não sabe exatamente como ou porquê.

Vou bolar uma solução para o seu problema X:

```
public class Avaliador {

    private Avaliador() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static void avaliar(
            Trabalho trabalho,
            int intervalo)
    {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            while (!trabalho.terminou()) {
                System.out.println(trabalho.getStatus());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(intervalo * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(trabalho.getStatus());
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

```
public interface Trabalho {
    public boolean terminou();
    public String getStatus();
}
```

```
public class TrabalhoPesado implements Trabalho {

    private final String nome;
    private final int tamanho;
    private final Thread trabalhador;
    private volatile int tempoQuePassou;

    private TrabalhoPesado(String nome, int tamanho) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
        this.trabalhador = new Thread(this::trabalhar);
    }

    private void trabalhar() {
        while (tempoQuePassou < tamanho) {
            try {
                tempoQuePassou++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static TrabalhoPesado novoTrabalho(String nome, int tamanho) {
        TrabalhoPesado tp = new TrabalhoPesado(nome, tamanho);
        tp.trabalhador.start();
        return tp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean terminou() {
        return !trabalhador.isAlive();
    }

    @Override
    public String getStatus() {
        return "Trabalho: " + nome + ". Tempo que passou: " + tempoQuePassou + ". Terminou: " + terminou();
    }
}
```

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trabalho t1 = TrabalhoPesado.novoTrabalho("Azul", 120);
        Avaliador.avaliar(t1, 10);
        Trabalho t2 = TrabalhoPesado.novoTrabalho("Verde", 60);
        Avaliador.avaliar(t2, 1);
    }
}
```

Deixe esse programa rodando por dois minutos e ele vai produzir essa saída (ou algo parecido, linhas de saída de trabalhos diferentes feitos ao mesmo tempo pode aparecer em ordens distintas):

```
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 1. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 1. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 2. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 3. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 4. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 5. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 6. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 7. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 8. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 9. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 10. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 10. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 11. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 12. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 13. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 14. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 15. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 16. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 17. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 18. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 19. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 20. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 20. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 21. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 22. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 23. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 24. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 25. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 26. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 27. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 28. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 29. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 30. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 30. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 31. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 32. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 33. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 34. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 35. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 36. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 37. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 38. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 39. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 40. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 40. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 41. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 42. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 43. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 44. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 45. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 46. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 47. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 48. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 49. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 50. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 50. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 51. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 52. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 53. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 54. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 55. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 56. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 57. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 58. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 59. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 60. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 60. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Verde. Tempo que passou: 60. Terminou: true
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 70. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 80. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 90. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 100. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 110. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 120. Terminou: false
Trabalho: Azul. Tempo que passou: 120. Terminou: true
```

Observe que você pode ajustar os números do `Avaliador` para definir a frequência com a qual ele verifica o andamento do trabalho. Quando ele perceber que o trabalho terminou, ele para. Você pode executar vários trabalhos paralelamente, cada qual com o seu próprio avaliador independente dos demais.

A interface `Trabalho` especifica que um trabalho deve ter um método para determinar se ele já terminou e um para dar o status a ser visto pelo `Avaliador`. A implementação `TrabalhoPesado` aqui não faz nada muito importante, mas você provavelmente vai utilizar uma implementação diferente dessa interface.

Comment: Aquele momento que você sabe o que precisa mas não sabe explicar... Muito obrigado parceiro!